# Deploy App function with private endpoint via Azure DevOps

Tags: function, devops, private, endpoint

When we run release pipeline for Azure App function with private endpoint, Below error happens Error: Failed to fetch Kudu App Settings. Error: Ip Forbidden (CODE: 403)